# Foreman start hangs

Tags: node.js, heroku, express, foreman, heroku-toolbelt

I'm trying to make an express (currently working) application to work with `foreman start`.

This is my `Procfile`:

```
web: node ./bin/www
```

This is my `www`  file:

```
#!/usr/bin/env node
var debug = require('debug')('quiz');
var app = require('../app');

app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);

var server = app.listen(app.get('port'), function() {
  debug('Express server listening on port ' + server.address().port);
});
```

And this is my `package.json`:

```
{
  "name": "quiz",
  "version": "0.0.0",
  "private": true,
  "scripts": {
    "start": "node ./bin/www"
  },
  "engines": {
    "node": "0.10.x",
    "npm": "1.4.x"
  },
  "devDependencies": {
    "sqlite3": "^3.0.8"
  },
  "dependencies": {
    "body-parser": "~1.8.1",
    "cookie-parser": "~1.3.3",
    "debug": "~2.0.0",
    "ejs": "~0.8.5",
    "express": "~4.9.0",
    "express-partials": "^0.3.0",
    "morgan": "~1.3.0",
    "pg": "^4.1.1",
    "pg-hstore": "^2.3.2",
    "sequelize": "^1.7.0",
    "serve-favicon": "~2.1.3"
  }
}
```

When I run `foreman start` in the log everything looks alright:

```
23:17:21 web.1  | started with pid 1632
```

When I test it in my browser the request are shown in the log but nothing reach the browser.

This is de log when I try to browse to `http://localhost:5000/`:

```
23:20:56 web.1  | ←[0mGET / ←[32m200 ←[0m25.741 ms - 1404←[0m
23:20:56 web.1  | ←[0mGET /stylesheets/style.css ←[36m304 ←[0m5.098 ms - -←[0m
23:20:56 web.1  | ←[0mGET /stylesheets/wide.css ←[36m304 ←[0m4.419 ms - -←[0m
```

The request seems to be resolved but the browser keeps waiting for response indefinitely. Finally the browser shows ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE.

I try to make some other arbitrary request with the same result:

```
23:23:08 web.1  | ←[0mGET /author ←[32m- ←[0m- ms - -←[0m
23:23:08 web.1  | ←[0mGET /stylesheets/smartphone.css ←[32m- ←[0m- ms - -←[0m
23:25:59 web.1  | ←[0mGET /author ←[32m- ←[0m- ms - -←[0m
23:28:00 web.1  | ←[0mGET /author ←[32m- ←[0m- ms - -←[0m
23:30:00 web.1  | ←[0mGET /author ←[32m- ←[0m- ms - -←[0m
```

Any idea of how could I debug this in order to figure what's happening?

Thanks in advance.

Comment: Initially, you said `app.set('port', process.env.PORT || 3000);`, but lower, you said `http://localhost:5000/` - are you accessing the server on the correct port?

Comment: Before add the foreman configuration, i started it with "npm start". In this way all works fine. But after configure it to start with "foreman start" it listens at port 5000.

Comment: I'm saying that you're setting port to `3000` first then opening `5000`. What does your actual `.listen` command to express look like? Does it use the `port` value or some other value?

Comment: Foreman listen to the port provided in the env variable $PORT. I've changed it in my .env file by adding a line with `PORT=3000`. Now it listen at 3000. I'v tryed again (now at http:\\localhost:3000) with de same result :(

Answer (score 1, accepted):

Heroku [no longer supports foreman](https://devcenter.heroku.com/changelog-items/692) so the best approach would be to try using their recommended alternative to foreman instead: the heroku command "local".

The implementation is trivial:

- Download and install the latest version of heroku toolbelt (which no longer includes foreman).
- Instead of using `foreman start` use `heroku local`.

See heroku's web site for full details of [heroku local](https://devcenter.heroku.com/articles/heroku-local).

Although you don't mention it, is it possible that the reason you are getting those ERR_EMPTY_RESPONSE messages is because foreman had died (rather than "hung") while handling the request? I had the same problem with some stylesheets after foreman had logged the message "sending SIGKILL to all processes" to the console, and terminated. Regardless, my problems vanished when I used `heroku local` instead of `foreman start`.

And even if `heroku local` also fails, that should become the issue to resolve rather than your current problem with foreman.

Comment: Eventually I moved to a Linux development environment. Since then everything works fine me. In either case, thanks for your answer. I will use 'heroku local' for future developments.